# Create unique checkboxes dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to create checkboxes from a "input type number". This is how far ive come:

Fiddle: [My current CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/7mBRu/28/)

**html**

```
 <div id="positions">
    <input type="number" class="txt" value="1" style="width: 30px"/>
    <button type="button" class="btnPos">Add pos</button>
 </div>
```

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".btnPos").on('click', function () {
       $('#positions').append('<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" />' 
           + "Pos " + $(".txt").val());
   });
});
```

Now I create checkboxes like this: [] pos 1 etc. But I want to create like 7 at the same time. Lets say I choose the number "3" in the input. I want it to create 3 boxes like this: **[ ] pos 1 , [ ] pos 2 , [ ] pos 3.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more what you wanted (following the right pos indexes as you add them) :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btnPos").on('click', function () {

        for(var i=1; i<=$(".txt").val(); i++)
        {
            var numItems = 0;
            if ( $('input[type="checkbox"]') )    
            {
                numItems = $('input[type="checkbox"]').length + 1;
            }
            $('#positions').append('<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" />' + "Pos " + numItems);
        }
    });
});
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/7mBRu/32/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btnPos").on('click', function () {

    for(var i=1; i<=$(".txt").val(); i++)
    {
        $('#positions').append('<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" />' + "Pos " + i);
    }
    });
});

below is the working fiddle
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7mBRu/29/